# How to omit a manifest attribute in Ant, if the value is empty?

Tags: ant

This defines a manifest in Ant:

```
<manifest>
  <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
</manifest>
```

How can I omit an empty main class entry in the manifest, when the property contains an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only clean solution is to write the `ant` task twice: with and without manifest.

But if you don't want to do this, you could use following trick. Create two manifest files: one with main class and one without. The main class in the first manifest should be replaced with a placeholder (token) (e. g. `@main-class@`). Then you can do

```
<condition
    property="manifest-file"
    value="manifest-without-main-class.mf"
    else="manifest-with-main-class.mf"
>
    <length string="${main-class}" trim="true" length="0" />
</condition>

<copy file="manifest-template.mf" tofile="manifest-with-main-class.mf"/>
<replace
    file="manifest-with-main-class.mf"
    token="@main-class@"
    value="${manifest-file}"
/>

<jar manifest="${manifest-file}" ...>
   ...
</jar>
```

With `manifest-template.mf`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: ...
Built-By: ...
Main-Class: @main-class@
```

And `manifest-without-main-class.mf`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: ...
Built-By: ...
```

Comment: This means 3 templates for 2 optional attributes and 6 templates for 3 optional attributes.

Comment: Uff. This seems to be a no go. I have very long class paths in my manifest.

Comment: This is "just" a readability issue. You could also write multiple `jar` tags and choose the right one using ant-contrib `if` tag or target `if` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You could also optionally update your manifest using 'update' mode:

```
<ac:if>
    <length string="${module.dependencies}" trim="true" when="greater" length="0" />
    <then>
        <echo>Adding Dependencies (${module.dependencies}) to manifest file ${manifest-file}</echo>
        <manifest file="${manifest-file}" mode="update">
            <attribute name="Dependencies" value="${module.dependencies}" />
        </manifest>
    </then>
</ac:if>
```

This will only add the attribute you need when it's fill-in.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make use of the `<macrodef>` task's ability to pass arbitrary elements into it.

### build.xml

The following script uses the third-party Ant-Contrib library.

```
<project name="ant-macrodef-with-optional-element" default="test" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

    <macrodef name="create-manifest">
        <attribute name="file"/>
        <attribute name="main-class"/>
        <sequential>
            <if>
                <length string="@{main-class}" length="0"/>
                <then>
                    <create-manifest-internal file="@{file}"/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <create-manifest-internal file="@{file}">
                        <main-class-attribute>
                            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="@{main-class}"/>
                        </main-class-attribute>
                    </create-manifest-internal>
                </else>
            </if>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <macrodef name="create-manifest-internal">
        <attribute name="file"/>
        <element name="main-class-attribute" optional="yes" />
        <sequential>
            <manifest file="@{file}">
                <main-class-attribute/>
            </manifest>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="test">
        <create-manifest file="manifest-1-out.txt" main-class="com.example.Main"/>
        <loadfile property="manifest-1-out-result" srcFile="manifest-1-out.txt"/>
        <echo>manifest-1-out.txt:</echo>
        <echo>${manifest-1-out-result}</echo>

        <create-manifest file="manifest-2-out.txt" main-class=""/>
        <loadfile property="manifest-2-out-result" srcFile="manifest-2-out.txt"/>
        <echo>manifest-2-out.txt:</echo>
        <echo>${manifest-2-out-result}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
test:
     [echo] manifest-1-out.txt:
     [echo] Manifest-Version: 1.0
     [echo] Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
     [echo] Created-By: 1.7.0_40-b43 (Oracle Corporation)
     [echo] Main-Class: com.example.Main
     [echo]
     [echo] manifest-2-out.txt:
     [echo] Manifest-Version: 1.0
     [echo] Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
     [echo] Created-By: 1.7.0_40-b43 (Oracle Corporation)
     [echo]
```

The main drawback of this approach is the duplication of attributes needed to pass values from the caller to the outer macrodef and then to the inner macrodef.

Answer (score 0):

My *Ant* skills are not great but I solved it this way. It's bit of a hack but it does use only one `jar` task. It puts in the `Main-Class` if required, otherwise adds a bland `Comment` entry.

**build.xml**

```
<project name="Builder">

   <target name="default">
       <build-me name="FooBar" main-class="foo.bar.Main"/>
       <build-me name="BarFoo" />
   </target>

   <macrodef name="build-me">
       <attribute name="name" />
       <attribute name="main-class" default="" />
       <sequential>
          <tstamp>
             <format property="now" pattern="E d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" locale="en,UK"/>
          </tstamp>         

          <!-- Compile and other steps ommited -->

           <condition property="optional-main" value="Main-class" else="Comments">
              <and>
                 <not>
                    <equals arg1="" arg2="@{main-class}" />
                 </not>
             </and>
          </condition>
          <condition property="main-class" value="@{main-class}" else="no main class">
             <and>
                <not>
                   <equals arg1="" arg2="@{main-class}" />
                </not>
             </and>
          </condition>

          <jar destfile="@{name}.jar" basedir="build/@{name}">
             <manifest>
                <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${now}" />
                <attribute name="${optional-main}" value="${main-class}" />
            </manifest>
         </jar>
      </sequential>
   </macrodef>
</project>
```

Result:

**FooBar**

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Build-Date: Tue 2 Aug 2016 11:02:46 BST
Main-class: foo.bar.Main
```

**BarFoo**

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Build-Date: Tue 2 Aug 2016 11:02:46 BST
Comments: no main class
```

Comment: Please ignore this - it currently doesn't work!

Will post the correct solution soon once working. Otherwise I'll delete it.